# What is $\lim_{h\to0}\int_{-h}^h \delta(i+x)f(x)dx$?

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045521/2513) says that

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(i+x)f(x)dx=f(-i)$
(for well-behaved functions).

But what happens if we make the limits of integration to go to zero? What is $$\lim_{h\to0}\int_{-h}^h \delta(i+x)f(x)dx$$?

Is the answer the same?

Comment: Ignore the limit for a moment and focus on the integral. It should be clear that the integral is $f(-i)$ for any $h>0$. So we have $\lim_{h \to 0} f(-i)=f(-i)$. Note that we never need to consider h=0 in evaluating the limit. If you try to make h=0 then you don;t have an integral any more.

Comment: @DavidShaffer thanks, but this is not enough clear. Should we say that $\delta(a+i)=0$ for any $\Re(a)\ne0$?

Comment: @AdamLatosiński $\delta(x)
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}\, dk$, see the linked question.

Comment: How do you define $\int_{-h}^h \delta(x+i) f(x)dx$? Normally one would guess it's $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x+i) f(x) {\bf 1}_{[-h,h]}(x)dx$$, but $f(x) {\bf 1}_{[-h,h]}(x)$ is not a "well-behaved function" (it doesn't have a well-defined analytic contiuation), so you cannot define it like that.

Answer (score 2):

When you operate with distributions that are not proper functions, you cannot simply change the limits of integration. In a sense $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x+i) (\cdot) dx$$
is a single symbol and it has a mathematical meaning only as a whole, as the linear map
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x+i) (\cdot) dx : f \mapsto f(-i)$$
defined on a set of functions continuous at $-i$.

Before you ask about the limit $h \to 0$ you need to first properly define what
$$ \int_{-h}^h\delta(x+i) (\cdot) dx$$
and it's not obvious how it should be defined. If it was a real number $a$ in place of $i$ one would usually say that
$$ \int_{-h}^h\delta(x+a) (\cdot) dx : f \mapsto f(-a){\bf 1}_{[-h,h]}(-a) $$
and is defined on functions $f$ such that $f(x){\bf 1}_{[-h,h]}(x)$ is continuous at $x=-a$. You cannot however use this for $\delta(x+i)$, because ${\bf 1}_{[-h,h]}(x)$ is only defined for real arguments. Therefore, to get an answer you must first define what $\int_{-h}^h\delta(x+i) (\cdot) dx$ means.

Comment: I think the answer by reuns in the linked question is wrong because he possibly also assumed the $i$ in question was real. At least in his formulas we see $i (-i)$, which is strange.

Comment: I don't think he did, he clearly uses $i$ in the argumnet of the exponent as the imaginary unit, and he talks about the analytic continuation of $f$ which defines values of $f$ for complex numbers.

Comment: Basically, my question is, whether the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(i+x)f(x)dx$ mostly determined by the behaviour of $\delta(x)$ in the neighborhood of $i$. In other words, can we say that $\delta(i+a)=0$ always if $\Re(a)\ne 0$?

Comment: And Iwhat I'm saying is that $\delta(x)$ is not a function, and in particular it doesn't have a value at any point, so asking around its behaviour around $i$ is a nonsense. $\delta(x+i)$ is a symbol which, when used under an integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ denotes a specific functional. When used in a different context, it doesn't have a meaning, unless given one.

Comment: I already said that I consider the definition of $\delta(x)$ via Fourier transform, so it is possible to find its values at points.

Comment: Incorrect, $\delta(x)$ is a limit of Fourier transforms, and this limit doesn't exist in the sense of limits of functions. It only exists in the sense of limit of functionals.

Comment: If we insert exact values for certain arguments (say, 1), we can easily find the value of the Fourier transform, it will be $0$.

Comment: If I put $x=0$, I get the divergent integral $\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx$, so what? My question was not about $x=0$ though. If I put $x=i$ I also get divergent integral $\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x dx$. This integral seems greater than the previous one, so I wondered what I get if I integrate over it.

Comment: Even if you put other $x$ the limit doesn't exist in the sense of functions $$ \delta(x) = \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{-T}^T e^{2\pi i \xi x} d\xi = \lim_{T \to\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi x T) }{\pi x}$$

Comment: Well, the integral of sine $\int_{0}^\infty \sin x dx$ can be easily found via Cesaro integration (it is equal to 1)

Comment: No $\int \sin x dx$ appears here. And the integral you're talking about is not convergent, I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: It appears in the definition of $\delta(x)$ that I posted in the question if we insert $x=1$

Comment: A limit appears, not an integral. There's no limit $\lim_{T\to\infty} \sin(2\pi T)$

Comment: It is well Cesaro-summable and exists in all tables of Fourier transforms, so it does not matter if it is not convergent in the strictest sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120320/discussion-between-adam-latosinski-and-anixx).

Comment: There is no limit in the definition, only integrals. The integrals are Cesaro-summable for $x=1$.

Comment: Listen, if you have a definition of $\int_{-h}^h\delta(x+i) (\cdot) dx$, please add it to the question, because it's not clear to me what it is. If not, then my answer stands.